# RGB raster plot error in R

Tags: raster, r

I have multiple individual band `rasters` in `tif` format, and I tried creating a `RGB` raster from the `R`, `G`, `B` rasters in `R` using the `raster` package and then wrote it to disk. Now, apparently the RGB raster created just fine, as it loaded just fine in `ArcMap` as seen below. But, now when I try to plot the save RGB raster via `raster::plotRGB`, I get this error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘plotRGB’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer"’
```

And with `RSToolbox::ggRGB`, I get this error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'sampleRegular': not a valid subset
```

How can I fix this error? I even get the same error if I the write the raster stack to file and plot that. So, I think I am not writing the raster object to file correctly.

Code

```
library(raster)
library(RSToolbox)
R = raster("path/Red.tif")
G = raster("path/Green.tif")
B = raster("path/Blue.tif")

RGB = raster::stack(R, G, B)
RGB = raster::brick(RGB)

writeRaster(RGB , filename = "path/RGB.tif",overwrite  = TRUE)

RGB = raster("path/RGB.tif")

plotRGB(RGB) # Gives error

ggRGB(RGB) # Gives error
```

As shown in ArcMap

[image]

Basic raster layer info:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of

```
RGB = raster("path/RGB.tif")
```

You should do

```
RGB = brick("path/RGB.tif")
```

Or even better:

```
library(terra)
r = rast("path/RGB.tif")
plotRGB(r)

# or
RGB(r) <- 1:3
plot(r)
```

Comment: Is `terra` more preferred over `raster` now, just as `sf` is preferred over `sp`?

Comment: yes, it is --- if you ask me.  One advantage is that there is only `rast`, no need to choose between `raster`, `stack`, and `brick`